# spring boot with primefaces give error : java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: org/springframework/core/log/LogMessage

Tags: spring-boot, joinfaces

i am a newbie in spring boot and i am trying to build a simple spring boot project with primefaces using STS IDE . But when i run the programme i get an error as showed bellow :

```
2019-12-01 20:26:54.117 ERROR 5848 --- [           main] o.s.boot.SpringApplication               : 
 Application run failed

java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: org/springframework/core/log/LogMessage
    at org.springframework.boot.StartupInfoLogger.logStarting(StartupInfoLogger.java:55) ~[spring-boot-2.2.1.RELEASE.jar:2.2.1.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.logStartupInfo(SpringApplication.java:637) ~[spring-boot-2.2.1.RELEASE.jar:2.2.1.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.prepareContext(SpringApplication.java:373) ~[spring-boot-2.2.1.RELEASE.jar:2.2.1.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:314) ~[spring-boot-2.2.1.RELEASE.jar:2.2.1.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:1226) ~[spring-boot-2.2.1.RELEASE.jar:2.2.1.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:1215) ~[spring-boot-2.2.1.RELEASE.jar:2.2.1.RELEASE]
    at com.AliasBlue.springbootjsf.application.JsfPrimefacesHello3Application.main(JsfPrimefacesHello3Application.java:10) ~[classes/:na]
Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: org.springframework.core.log.LogMessage
    at java.base/jdk.internal.loader.BuiltinClassLoader.loadClass(BuiltinClassLoader.java:583) ~[na:na]
    at java.base/jdk.internal.loader.ClassLoaders$AppClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoaders.java:178) ~[na:na]
    at java.base/java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:521) ~[na:na]
    ... 7 common frames omitted
```

for the pom.xml of my project this is it  :

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 https://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
    <parent>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-parent</artifactId>
        <version>2.2.1.RELEASE</version>
        <relativePath/> <!-- lookup parent from repository -->
    </parent>
    <groupId>com.Alias-Blue</groupId>
    <artifactId>spring-boot-jsf</artifactId>
    <version>0.0.1-SNAPSHOT</version>
    <name>jsf-primefaces-hello-3</name>
    <description>PCA_CFS project with Spring Boot </description>

    <properties>
        <project.build.sourceEncoding>UTF-8</project.build.sourceEncoding>
        <project.reporting.outputEncoding>UTF-8</project.reporting.outputEncoding>
        <java.version>1.8</java.version>
        <joinfaces.version>4.0.1</joinfaces.version>
    </properties>

    <dependencies>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-integration</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-web</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-web-services</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-tomcat</artifactId>
        </dependency>


    <dependency>
      <groupId>org.joinfaces</groupId>
      <artifactId>primefaces-spring-boot-starter</artifactId>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
      <groupId>javax.enterprise</groupId>
      <artifactId>cdi-api</artifactId>
    </dependency>
  </dependencies>
    <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-test</artifactId>
            <scope>test</scope>
            <exclusions>
                <exclusion>
                    <groupId>org.junit.vintage</groupId>
                    <artifactId>junit-vintage-engine</artifactId>
                </exclusion>
            </exclusions>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.integration</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-integration-test</artifactId>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>
        </dependencies>
    <dependencyManagement>
        <dependencies>
            <dependency>
                <groupId>org.joinfaces</groupId>
                <artifactId>joinfaces-dependencies</artifactId>
                <version>${joinfaces.version}</version>
                <type>pom</type>
                <scope>import</scope>
            </dependency>
        </dependencies>
    </dependencyManagement>
    <build>
        <plugins>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
                <artifactId>spring-boot-maven-plugin</artifactId>
            </plugin>
        </plugins>
    </build>
</project>
```

i followed the steps from this site : https://codenotfound.com/jsf-primefaces-example.html

Comment: What's your pom.xml?

Comment: i posted my pom.xml in answer look it and help please , thanks in advance .

Comment: Sour join faces version depends on spring boot stuff 2.1, but you added 2.2. This may cause issues:  https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.joinfaces/jsf-spring-boot-starter/4.0.1

Comment: But it gives this error : The Tomcat connector configured to listen on port 8080 failed to start. The port may already be in use or the connector may be misconfigured.

Comment: when i run it the second time in the same port it gives that error , so i should always change the port of server . please how can i solve this problem ?

Comment: You are welcome - but please ask 1 question per question only.

Answer (score 3):

The version [4.0.1 of Join Faces](https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.joinfaces/jsf-spring-boot-starter/4.0.1) used depends on spring-boot-starter 2.1.1 while version 2.2.1 was added to the POM. This caused the `java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError`.

Answer (score -1):

The version 4.0.1 of Join Faces used on spring-boot-starter 2.1.1.RELEASE

So you can use 4.1.1 join faces for spring-boot-starter 2.2.1.RELEASE
Please check the below link and you can refer corresponding spring-boot & joinfaces dependency combinations.

https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.joinfaces/jsf-spring-boot-starter
https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.joinfaces/jsf-spring-boot-starter/4.1.1